# View model in knockout js is null on page load

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

How to get the view model in knoclout js on Page load event?

I'm calling this function "fetchExisitingWidgets()" in page load.
Here is my code, but the problem is the ViewModel is null because the model is not constructed yet! I have tried to get the view model after loading the page but the viewModel get the value if I pressed ctrl+R, Any one has faced this problem?

```
var fetchExisitingWidgets = function () {
    var viewModel = ko.dataFor($("#ListViewWidget").get(0));
    var allWidgets = webAppContext.appContent.Widgets;

};
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if the script that calls your function is being loaded before the one that builds your ViewModel. Ideally, use a loader like RequireJS that ensures that scripts don't run until all their dependencies have run.